# Create password protected zip in Java

Tags: java, encryption, zip, passwords

My question is similar to this one: [Write a password protected Zip file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166340/write-a-password-protected-zip-file-in-java), but what I need is to create password protected zip file using mechanism simpler than AES beause not every archive manager can unpack AES-protected zip files (for example WinRar is not able to do that). Do you know some free library that can password protect zip file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want old style zip password protection rather than the new AES encryption, your choices are limited.  A quick search has turned up neither source code nor free libraries to handle the old stuff.   Your best bet is probably calling a command line zip tool, assuming one is installed.

At this point I'd ask myself why I'm even bothering to use the old style password protection, as its extremely easy to crack (a few hours tops).  About all it stops is mildly nosy nontechnical people.