# Execute winzip command in a java program

Tags: java, runtime.exec

Need to execute the below winzip command in a java program.

```
C:\Program Files\WinZip>winzip32 -a -s"password" C:\abc.zip C:\abc.doc
```

Comment: Are you aware that java includes native support for compressing/decompressing zip files? It's better to use pure java because your application will be cross platform as opposed to Windows-only.

Comment: @Asaph: He want to create a password protected zip file.

Comment: @BalusC: I noticed that after I posted my comment, when I read your answer, which I upvoted. :)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Runtime#exec()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) ([tutorial here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090806070132/http://java.sun.com/developer/JDCTechTips/2003/tt0304.html), [caveats here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100203124517/http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)) or just pure Java code ([related SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166340/write-a-password-protected-zip-file-in-java)).

By the way, if you didn't need password protection, you could just go ahead with [`java.util.zip`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) ([tutorial here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100826031009/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/)).

Comment: Also, if you intend to have lots of threads be able to call out I suggest limiting the number of threads that can call out at a time.

Comment: +1: Using java.util.zip gives you cross-platform support, doesn't rely on an install of WinZip etc. If it's an option to use, where possible, do so.

Answer (score 2):

You can simple use [Runtime.exec()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[]));

```
String[] cmd = {"C:\\Program Files\\WinZip\\winzip32", "-a", "-s", "password", "C:\\abc.zip", "C:\\abc.doc"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look around the internet, would this do what you're looking for: https://truezip.dev.java.net/ without having to rely on an external install of WinZip which may or may not exist on the end user system? Just a suggestion.