# Need suggestions for a good way to encrypt/decrypt data stored in SQLite database on Android

Tags: database, android, sqlite, encryption

I have some sensitive data that is stored in SQLite for an Android app. I need to be able to encrypt when persisting but then also decrypting when deserializing from the database too. Not sure what my options are on Android for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No simple answer here. Guess Ill just use something simple to mangle the column values when serializing.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing built into Android for encrypting database contents. You are welcome to encrypt/decrypt values yourself and store the encrypted material in the database, but that's up to you, and would have to be done on a cell-by-cell basis.

For encryption algorithms, Android has `javax.crypto` built in.

Also, bear in mind that if your encryption key is baked into your application, anyone who cares to will be able to get past your encryption.

Comment: I am trying to understand why is this is so hard to get any good post about this topic... I don't want to encrypt the data cell by cell.. neither keep it open I am okay ieven if it's not full proof... at least some level of protection is good... what options do I have? where am I suppose to copy DB file...directly on the SDCard... or some specific location on SDCard ? I have around 30 mb of db

Comment: I decided to use this way: store only encrypted data as blobs - byte[]. It is fast and packed well.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166340/write-a-password-protected-zip-file-in-java) regarding reading/writing password-protected zip files.  It includes a few links to some OSS libraries that perform these tasks.  Though you're not necessarily interested in compression, this could potentially solve the problem of decrypting the db at startup and then you could simply write the modified database back to the encrypted file.

@CommonsWare is absolutely right in that baking the password/key into your app means that someone who really wanted to could get at your data.  However, I think it would prevent most people from swiping your data through trivial means.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to encrypt your database, you're probably using a log-in to your app for security, right? Why not have your log-in server store your "secret code" for the encryption and once they log-in, pull the "secret code" and store the code (in a public string, not to an actual file or preference). This way, if someone decompiles your app they still won't be able to decrypt the data and your data will be safe.

Then use:

On `Destroy()` to clear the code every time the app unloads.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/) for encrypting the database..

Answer (score -2):

You can try encripting in SHA1

```
public static String encriptSHA1(String password){
        String hash = "";

        try {
            MessageDigest md;
            byte[] buffer, digest;

            buffer = password.getBytes();
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");

            md.update(buffer);
            digest = md.digest();

            for(byte aux : digest) {
                int b = aux & 0xff;
                if (Integer.toHexString(b).length() == 1) hash += "0";
                hash += Integer.toHexString(b);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }

        return hash;
    }
```

Comment: SHA1 is a one-way hashing algorithm and therefor can't be used in this scenario.

Comment: Yes, I need to encrypt when storing in the database but then decrypt when needed by my application.