# How to open password protected zip file using truezip library in java

Tags: java, zip, truezip

Please show me sample of code how to open password protected file using truezip library.

If you don't have a link to sample code please show me method to open this file.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166340/write-a-password-protected-zip-file-in-java): several suggestion are available. A quick google search make me thinks that TrueZip supports only its own encryption: read [here](http://markmail.org/message/txxo6twd5l5lirmh#query:java%20truezip%20password+page:1+mid:dn4vi6j4gpvnxn7d+state:results)

Answer (score 0):

TrueZIP supports only its own encryption scheme: ZIP.RAES alias TZP

Any other ZIP encryption scheme, e.g. WinZIP encryption, is not available at this time.

If you want this feature supported, you can vote for it here: http://java.net/jira/browse/TRUEZIP-9