# How to encrypt zip file using zip4j

Tags: java, zip

I want to create password protected ZIP:

```
    // Set the compression level
    parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);

    // Set the encryption flag to true
    // If this is set to false, then the rest of encryption properties are ignored
    parameters.setEncryptFiles(true);

    // Set the encryption method to Standard Zip Encryption
    parameters.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_STANDARD);

    // Set password
    parameters.setPassword(password);
```

but this just encrypt files inside of zip but I can open this zip and watch file inside it

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166340/write-a-password-protected-zip-file-in-java

Comment: I dont think so. In your thread there are list of libraries which you can use for creating zip but I choose one and I need help with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip4j does not support the encryption of the file list because of patent issues.

See: http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/forum/index.php?topic=104.0

**Update:**

As stated in the link. The zip-specification does not include the encryption of the filelist. To hide the filenames you can create a zip-file including your files encapsulate it by zip it again. Hence if you open zip2.zip you will only see "zip1.zip" and not the original filenames.

Comment: PKWare provides it's own tool called SecureZIP. It supports file name encryption

Answer (score 5):

[Zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/index.php) supports the encryption of the file list...

> [Key features](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/index.php):
>
> - Create, Add, Extract, Update, Remove files from a Zip file
> - Read/Write password protected Zip files
> - **Supports AES 128/256 Encryption**
> - **Supports Standard Zip Encryption**
> - Supports Zip64 format
> - Supports Store (No Compression) and Deflate compression method
> - Create or extract files from Split Zip files (Ex: z01, z02,...zip)
> - Supports Unicode file names
> - Progress Monitor

Take a look at this example code [AddFilesWithAESEncryption.java](https://github.com/dmp/zip4j/blob/master/src/net/lingala/zip4j/examples/zip/AddFilesWithAESEncryption.java):

```
// Initiate ZipFile object with the path/name of the zip file.
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("c:\\ZipTest\\AddFilesWithAESZipEncryption.zip");

// Build the list of files to be added in the array list
// Objects of type File have to be added to the ArrayList
ArrayList filesToAdd = new ArrayList();
filesToAdd.add(new File("c:\\ZipTest\\sample.txt"));
filesToAdd.add(new File("c:\\ZipTest\\myvideo.avi"));
filesToAdd.add(new File("c:\\ZipTest\\mysong.mp3"));

// Initiate Zip Parameters
ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
// set compression method to deflate compression
parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE); 
parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_ULTRA); 

// Set the encryption flag to true
parameters.setEncryptFiles(true);

// Set the encryption method to AES Zip Encryption
parameters.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_AES);

// Set AES Key strength. Key strengths available for AES encryption are:
parameters.setAesKeyStrength(Zip4jConstants.AES_STRENGTH_256);

// Set password
parameters.setPassword("test123!");

// Now add files to the zip file
zipFile.addFiles(filesToAdd, parameters);
```

Comment: setPassword is deprecated. New version is:

ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("filename.zip", "password".toCharArray());