# How to encrypt a zip byte[] array in memory

Tags: java, encryption, zip, in-memory

I already have one `byte[]` for zip file in memory. Now I want encrypt it, when user download it, it can be open use a tools like `winRAR` and enter the password.

I've tried `zip4j`, btu it does not support stream.

How can I do it?

Comment: I think you can find more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166340/write-a-password-protected-zip-file-in-java

Comment: thank you! I find out the solution on this page http://code.google.com/p/encrypt-zip-as3-java/source/browse/trunk/EncryptZip/src/nochump/util/extend/ZipOutput2Flex.java

Comment: Hi coffee, and welcome to stackoverflow (a bit late, but better late then never :) ). You can post your solution as an answer to your own question. It seems separate from the link that maqjav posted, so it's fine to stand on its own, especially if the zip was already in memory...