# Support for password protected zip files in hdfs?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, zipinputstream

We were using zipinputstream for reading the zip files present in hdfs.But now we had password protected zip files.Is there any way to decode the zip files in hdfs only,before passing it to zipinputstream?There is a java library zip4j,which works with local file system only,but since we had huge amount of files,we want to decode and open the files in hdfs only.Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180597/how-to-unzip-files-stored-in-hdfs-using-java-without-first-copying-to-the-local

Comment: and this http://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2013/12/28/Reading-data-from-HDFS-even-if-it-is-compressed.html

Comment: @TahirHussainMir-Thanks but I had already done that stuff.With normal zip files,it works fine,the problem is I had password protected zip files.

Comment: This post content might help you, have alook http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738929/processing-password-protected-zip-files-using-mapreduce