# Create password protected archive with SevenZipBinding

Tags: java, zip

Can [SevenZipBinding](http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/) create password-protected archive? According to documentation it supports extracting of password-protected archive and creating of archive, but I don't see, does it support creating of password-protected archive.

Comment: It doesn't look like it. But there are other options listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166340/write-a-password-protected-zip-file-in-java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SevenZipBinding currently does not support creating of password-protected archives. It is a planned functionality.